# Percentage countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle, counter, jcycle

I'm doing a countdown from 100% to 0% using jQuery or JavaScript. I'm trying work out how to do this and have control over what percentage it stops at. So far I've put together this using a plugin called jCycle because I can apply `fx none`, set speed and timeout and also use `autostop` and `autostopCount`. I need it to count down quickly but not sure of a better way.

Although I know it's clunky my code is below to hopefully help give you a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve. For example purposes I have just shown from 10% - 0%:

```
<div id="counter">
   <p>1%</p>
   <p>2%</p>
   <p>3%</p>
   <p>4%</p>
   <p>5%</p>
   <p>6%</p>
   <p>7%</p>
   <p>8%</p>
   <p>9%</p>
   <p>10%</p>
</div>
```

```
$('#counter').cycle({
    delay: 600,
    fx:     'none',
    backwards: true,
    speed: 1,
    timeout:  60, 
        autostop: 1,
    autostopCount: 0,
});
```

How can I consolidate my HTML? There are too many `p` tags I have to type manually.

Comment: I see you're new to SO, so be sure to click the green checkmark next to the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `autostopCount` to how many items you want to count down. So if you're starting at 100 and want to stop at 5, set `autostopCount: 96`. The formula is thus: `stop = start - (difference - 1)`.

You can pass in any `var` to your `.cycle()` function and change it programmatically.

To avoid typing out 100 `p` tags, just use a `for` loop!

```
for(i=1; i <= 100; i++) {
    $('#counter').append('<p>' + i + '%');
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/joshsmith/WE3UA/4/)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Surely there must be a way of consolidating this code though? This has to go from 100-0 so with this method I'd be looking to have 100 p tags inside the counter div. Is another method possible?

Comment: @tweedman23 Ah, didn't realize that was part of your problem. Added.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to consolidate your html so that all you need is:

```
<div id="counter">
    <p><span>100</span>%</p>
</div>
```

Then the jQuery will look like this:

```
var stop = 6;

function decrease(){
    var percent = Number($('#counter span').text());
    if(percent > stop){
        $('#counter span').text(--percent);
        var t = setTimeout(decrease,1000);
    }
}
setTimeout(decrease,1000);
```

I made a jsFiddle also: http://jsfiddle.net/gS4Rr/1/

If it isn't going fast enough feel free to change the 1000 to something smaller.